# How to put data to Hbase without using java

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

Are there any way to read data from a file and put them into Hbase table without using any java? I tried to store data from pig script by using

`sample = LOAD '/mapr/user/username/sample.txt' AS (all:chararray);`
`STORE deneme INTO 'hbase://sampledata' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('mysampletable:intdata');`

but this gave this error message:

> > ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filterWritableByteArrayComparable
> >
> > ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/WritableByteArrayComparable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pig seems like a good idea to import data into HBase. Check what Armon suggested about setting the `$PIG_CLASSPATH`.

Another possibility to bulk loading data into HBase is to use featured tools like `ImportTsv` (Tab Separated Values) and `CompleteBulkLoad`.

http://hbase.apache.org/book/ops_mgt.html#importtsv

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's the [Stargate](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate) REST interface, which is usable from any language.  It's not perfect, but it's worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure that $PIG_CLASSPATH also points at hbase.jar